# How to add a value that isn't defined in chart template

Tags: apache-flink, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

Trying to deploy flink using [bitnami Helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/flink)
I want to add `imagePullSecrets` to the final rendered chart but it isn't defined in the [parent template](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/flink/templates/jobmanager/deployment.yaml) (try ctrl+f pullsecrets).

How can I do this? Simply adding an `imagePullSecrets` to the `values.yaml` doesn't do anything cuz helm just ignores it. Below is an example of what I've tried:

```
flink:
  image:
    registry: "docker.io"
    repository: "bitnami/flink"
    tag: "1.17.1"
    pullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
    imagePullSecrets:
      - my-secret
```

Comment: The Helm values only define _configuration_.  The output of the chart is based on what's in the chart's `templates` directory.  If a chart doesn't define a way to provide a specific Kubernetes setting, you can't (easily) add it without modifying the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the chart you linked [declares a dependency](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/common).

Hopefully that link will lead you to the right syntax.